# communicating between applications (.NET + java)

Tags: .net, communication

I have a pretty general question here. What is the best + reliable way for two applications running on the same machine to communicate with each other WITHOUT using web services or a web server of any kind.

as example:

application A: runs at .NET app that with active X controls can access another third party application and receive data.

application B: (lets assume is running java) wants to be able to start a process in application A with specific parameters and receive information back from application A. (no web services allowed)

the only thing I can think of is perhaps application B executing a file with certain parameters...then application A does any work and writes any return information into a database...but I don't know how reliable this is...or how application A would know when the data has been written to the database. (plus this sounds like a bit of a hackish solution to me..and was wondering is there anything better out there)

alright...thanks for any help!..

Andrew

Comment: Web services don't really involve using a web server. A webservice behaves like one, but this is just how the communication works. You can even have a small html interface documenting your web service. Is there any specific reason you don't want to use a web service?

Comment: i don't want to deal with IIS...having issues working with 3 party dll's,..especially when changing from 32-bit to 64-bit systems.

Comment: (i should say that I always assumed web service = using a web server/HTTP protocol)

Comment: Then you could consider using web services after all, since they don't require a web server although they might act as one.

Comment: Check my answer for more info on using web services for java .net interop

Comment: well if you don't use a web server for web services...what do you use for a communication portal??....sockets??

I hate the term "web services". I find it is very vague. Does is just mean using SOAP or XML as a communication language?

Comment: k nevermind...found some good information about it. I think I am going to use WCF.

Comment: Yes, traditionally a web service was bound to a TCP socket listening on a certain port and using SOAP as the commuication protocol. In WCF you aren't necessarily bound to a specific transport or communication protocol.

Comment: That's indeed your best option, if you choose to go for web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tcp sockets should be pretty reliable, even more so in the same machine. It doesn't need web services, web servers, etc - just a socket on each side.

Comment: Thanks!...if you don't mind could you elaborate ohow do tcp sockets stack up to web services?

Comment: As Adam Frisby pointed out, there are xmlrpc and soap libraries to build inter process communication without needing a web server.

Comment: One more clarification if possible:  by using xmlrpc and soap libraries do you just mean serializing my data into "SOAP form"...sending it over using sockets....then de-serializing it on the other end?....is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: Basically, for an object to be able to fit in a SOAP packet, after serialization it is encoded into base64. Since this isn't exactly performant, often MTOM(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM) is used for binary transmissions.

Comment: so is that a yes? (only I have to convert it to binary also)

Comment: It is a "you don't need to worry about it" when using webservices. The serialization and deserialization happens seemlessly. Or are you considering raw sockets?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the answers I would alos like to say that I looked into WCF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation

This is what I am going to use. I found this article very helpful:

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/04/20/wcf-simple-example.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A socket will be fairly easy to setup; however I suggest looking into something more akin to SOAP or XMLRPC - both will be a lot easier when it comes to packing and unpacking the data. Both .NET and Java both have extensive access and libraries availible for both XMLRPC and SOAP (both providers and consumers).

Comment: Thanks,..just to clarify:

When you say using soap do you just mean serializing my data into a SOAP object...sending it using a socket....then de-serializing it when it is sent?

thus I would still be using sockets? only using SOAP as my "communication language"...do not hesitate to slap me if I am not making sense here

Comment: Web services are typically bound to tcp sockets, but not necessarily. SOAP is just the communication protocol used to talk to the webservice. And your user objects are indeed serialized into something that will fit in the SOAP packet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as implementation is concerned, TCP sockets and web services are about as easy to set up on either side (client-server).

When performance is a consideration, TCP sockets will have the upperhand since there is less overhead.

But when it comes to useability, and ease of integration in the code I prefer web services. And honestly it is a much more transparent technology when it comes to debugging your code. The sockets counterpart will require more plumbing code before it gets useable.

Check out this [article](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive53.html) for more info on .NET and Java intercommunication via Web Services.